# set icon and text on image

Tags: html, css

I was try to set icons and text on images but it put extra space beside image, so how can i remove extra space from image?

```css
.fb {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 5px;
  z-index: 100;
}
.tweeter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 5px;
  z-index: 100;
}
img {
  overflow: hidden;
}
div {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif">
  <a class="fb" href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a class="tweeter" href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>

  <div>
  <img https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif">
  <a class="fb" href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a class="tweeter" href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>

  <div>
  <img https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif">
  <a class="fb" href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a class="tweeter" href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>

  <div>
  <img https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif">
  <a class="fb" href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a class="tweeter" href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the extra space? and Why have you tagged with [tag:jQuery]?

Comment: Make sure there are no spaces in your code.  ie not `<img\>\n    <a>` but `<img\><a..` (ie put them all on one line)

Comment: your img tags are not correct. should be `<img src="url">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first : your img tags are not correct. should be `<img src="url">`

second : `display:inline` generates white spaces between elements. so i suggest you use `float:left` instead

for example if you want 4 divs on one row, use `float:left;width:25%;` that way you are sure there are no white spaces between the `divs`

also to be sure the img covers all the width of the div, use `width:100%;height:auto` on the `img`. plus `overflow:hidden` on the `img` has no effect . you can use it on the `div` instead

see snippet below :

```css
.fb {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 5px;
  z-index: 100;
}
.tweeter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 5px;
  z-index: 100;
}
img {
 
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
div {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
 float:left;
  width:25%;
  position:relative;
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif">
  <a class="fb" href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a class="tweeter" href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
<div>
  <img src ="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif">
  <a class="fb" href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a class="tweeter" href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
<div>
  <img src ="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif">
  <a class="fb" href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a class="tweeter" href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
<div>
  <img src ="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif">
  <a class="fb" href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a class="tweeter" href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```